Cauchy's theorem in group theory
Let $p$ be a prime. Let $G$ be a finite group and let $p$ divide $|G|$. Then $G$ has an element of order $p$ and, consequently, a subgroup of order $p$.
I'm using the text "A first course in Abstract Algebra" by John B Fraleigh.
Here we have constructed the set $X$ as
$$
X = \{\ (g_1,g_2,...,g_p)\ |\ g_i\in 
G\ ,\  g_1g_2...g_p=e\}\ $$
It says that since $g_p=(g_1g_2...g_{p-1})^{-1}$. Thus $|X|=|G|^{p-1}$.
I didn't understand how we got this value?

After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: How do I accept an answer?, Why should we accept answers?, What should I do if someone answers my question?.

The first $p-1$ entries of such a tuple from $X$ may be freely chosen from $G$.  There are clearly $|G|^{p-1}$ such choices to fill out all but the last slot of the tuple.  The last slot is then dictated by the requirement that the product be $e$, which is the point of the stated identity $g_p=(g_1g_2\cdots g_{p-1})^{-1}$.

Actually I'm bit slow, how is that clearly $|G|^{p-1}$?

Because there are $|G|$ choices in each slot, and there are $p-1$ slots.  Basic combinatorics:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product
